# Not getting AT Translated Set 2 keyboard option when I run xinput list in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, xinput

I am new to Linux,

I wanted to disable my laptop's inbuilt keyboard,

The command **xinput --list** is not showing **AT Translated Set 2 keyboard**,

Instead it shows
virtual core keyboard

- Virtual core XTEST keyboard
- xwayland-keyboard:16

I just want to disable my internal keyboard,

Answer (score 1):

`xinput` is the command used by X11, you should use the Wayland command `libinput` instead. Check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426966